# Does the INotifyPropertyChanged standard implementation include a no-op if the value is the same as the current property?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

During a code review, it was suggested to implement my `INotifyPropertyChanged` as follows:

```
public string Prop
{
  get{return _prop;}
  set
  {
    if(_prop == value) return;
    _prop = value;
    OnPropertyChanged(()=>Prop);
  }
}
```

The line in question is:

> if(_prop == value) return;

My question is as to whether this is really necessary? I just ran into a case where `OnPropertyChanged` for a combobox was ignored by the framework if it returned the same reference anyway(I am not sure if this is true across the board, though?).

I personally don't see a need to add extra code clutter if it doesn't really make a difference. Does the framework implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` make the `if (_prop == value) return;` irrelevant or superfluous? Event with the framework impl aside, is this micro-optimization even warranted as a starting point?

Comment: I don't find it really necessary but it depends; if performance is a concern or there is some logic that hinges upon whether it has actually changed, you will want the check there.

Answer (score 4):

Very often, interfaces are contracts that have a semantic meaning rather than purely technical. In the case of INotifyPropertyChanged, the semantic meaning is exactly what it sounds like - the object implementing that interface notifies you when a property has changed.

The word 'changed' is key. Yes, a lot of classes that subscribe to the INotifyPropertyChanged event may be written in such a way that they compare the "new" value with what they had before, and if it hasn't actually changed they don't do anything. That's not something you should be relying on, though - if you're firing the event even when properties *haven't* changed, it's your code that's incorrect.

If client code does perform its own check as to whether the value has actually changed, that's them being ultra-cautious, but they aren't required and shouldn't be expected to do so.

Short version: yes, do the check in your INotifyPropertyChanged implementation. Don't expect client code to perform the check for you.

Comment: But, even with the client code aside, is this optimization really necessary? It shouldn't be a problem IMO

Comment: @JustinPihony We don't do opinions very well here. If you want to want to see if it's a problem or not, profile it, or ask in your question for someone to profile it.

Comment: You don't necessarily know what the client code is *doing* with the information. If it's performing expensive operations because you're telling it a property has changed when it hasn't, then yes it can cause a problem. The best approach is to simply write your INotifyPropertyChanged implementation correctly and then there *cannot* be a problem.

Comment: As an aside, doing the check isn't an optimization, it's the expected behaviour. *Not* bothering to do the check is the optimization, and should only be done if you're sure that (a) it's worth it and (b) it's not causing other problems down the line. You'd have to be doing an awful lot of property-sets for a simple equality check to be adding up to a significant performance impact.

Comment: An argument made by a co-worker is actually valid IMO. Somebody came in and said to set the value, so technically something did change by the definition that the set was hit. I think that is my personal take now after seeing other answers and his. It is that the impl is going to change depending on the situation, with the default behavior being that somebody said set, so technically a new value came in

Comment: I can't think of a single situation where I'd want to know that a property has been set to a value that it already had anyway. If you've got a genuine case where that's useful, go ahead, but it's not using the interface how it was intended.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not necessary. Usually do that when do not want to update the property when the value is equal to the old one. In this situation, I do so:

```
public string Prop
{
  get
  {
      return _prop;
  }

  set
  {
      if (_prop != value) 
      {
          _prop = value;
          OnPropertyChanged(()=>Prop);
      }
   }   
}
```

Comment: That's _exactly_ the same, just with the inverse if-statement :)

Comment: @khellang: I know, I like this construction more :).

Answer (score 1):

There is no *standard* implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged`, though most people/frameworks implement it in a base class along with the method you mentioned (using an [expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) to trigger the `PropertyChanged` event with the property name).

You don't mention where the method `OnPropertyChanged` comes from (or show the implementation), but generally the `if (_prop == value) return;` is used to avoid triggering the [`PropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged) event if the new value is the same as the old value.

Most people would argue that this is a micro optimization and not needed, but if you have a hot path where the value would change very frequently or much work would be done if it were triggered, it could be a good idea. Then again you might have another problem :P

In this case I find it hard to believe that the method could prevent the event from being triggered since it doesn't know the new value. The reason why some specific controls could ignore updates based on the event could be that they're comparing the values on the listening side, but your ViewModel has no guarantee that this is the case.